# How to Increase the connection timeout threshold in Socket/TcpClient C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, socketexception, networkstream

I have the connection from client to server using Socket/TcpClient. After I started it, the connection established between client and server, they can sent/recieved data between client and server. The server send data to client, and client will reply. This is working well during 13minutes. But after 13minutes, I get this error `Connection timed out. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.` . I go around and see this code `WSAETIMEDOUT 10060`. It's related to connection timeout. So, I don't know I can increase the connection timeout threshold, this way will increase the connection between client to server more than 13minutes probably. I try set some option like this, but I'm not sure what's the correct option.

```
    /*using Socket*/
    var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);           
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.120"), 5000);
    
    /*using TcpClient*/
    var client1 = new TcpClient();  
    client1.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.120"), 5000);
                
    ////which option should be choose in this case
    //client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);          
    //client.NoDelay = true; 
    //client.SendTimeout = 180000; 
    //client.ReceiveTimeout = 180000;  
    //client.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 180);
    //client.Ttl = 42;
    //client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    //client.Poll(180000000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
    //client.Poll(180000000, SelectMode.SelectWrite);
```

Comment: How are sure that the timeout has not been exceeded?

Comment: Hi, first if the connection not established, I will not see any data between client and server. Btw, i can see data from server, it's send link test data, after that client will reply. I have monitor it and observations that, it's working well through 13min, but after that catch exception with errors above.

Comment: You probably want the `TCP_MAXRT` option. But I doubt increasing the timeout will help, you probably have some kind of deadlock somewhere. Or maybe you need to implement a proper keepalive protocol. To be honest, why are you using raw sockets anyway, why not use a higher level protocol such as HTTP or WebSockets?

Comment: In my case, I used The High-Speed SECS Message Services (HSMS) protocol. Actually, this one based on TCP/IP. Btw, I used async method of this connection. And I tried all option above, but it's only 13min,

Comment: It's not a timeout problem.  TCP can stay open indefinitely and never send a packet.  Your problem is that one end, either server or client has stopped sending or receiving.  You will need to do a TCP trace to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I found resolve by myself, just spend more time to debug and see what's exactly data transfer. Besides, I use this code working well until now. So, if anyone get same issue, can try do like that.

```
  /*using Socket*/
    var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  
    client.ReceiveTimeout=180000;
    client.SendTimeout=180000;
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.120"), 5000);
    
    /*using TcpClient*/
    var client1 = new TcpClient();  
    client1.Client.ReceiveTimeout=180000;
    client1.Client.SendTimeout=180000;
    client1.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.120"), 5000);
```